# Conditional statement is not recognizing variable values

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple reaction time game for a final project.
We are using javascript to power the functions in the game, most of my code is in working order, but I have an if conditional statement that's giving me trouble.
Here's the code

```js
function fireTime() {
  setTimeout(ShotsFired, time);

  function ShotsFired() {
    fire.style.visibility = "visible";
    createdTime = Date.now();
    console.log(createdTime);
    EnemyTime = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 400);
    setTimeout(EnemyShoot, EnemyTime)

    function EnemyShoot() {
      console.log(EnemyTime);
      gameplay();
    }

    function gameplay() {
      reactionTime = -(createdTime - clickedTime);
      var EnemyTime;
      console.log(reactionTime);
      if (reactionTime < EnemyTime) {
        alert("Wow you beat him! Congrats!");
        fire.style.visibility = "hidden";
        clickedTime = 0;
        createdTime = 0;
        reactionTime = 0;
        scavnumber++;
        BGnumber++;
        DesertBG.src = "images/Desert" + BGnumber + ".png";
        scav.src = "images/scav" + scavnumber + ".png";
        fireTime();
      } else {
        EndScreen.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
```

This is not the entire code, just the function that should progress the game to the next level.

For whatever reason, even though reactionTime is less than EnemyTime, the EndScreen becomes visible.

Anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: var EnemyTime; <<< undefined converts to 0. remove the line and initialise it to a positive value outside the function

Comment: @Satpal it isn't initialised

Comment: @mplungjan, I am assuming OP has defined a global variable and redefined same in the function. Seems scope issue to me and I am egging him to share more info/code

Comment: So he needs to remove the line - If I did not understand your comment as egging, then he likely would also not :)

Comment: Okay I added the previous function so yall can see

Comment: I formatted the code for you. You need to REMOVE the `var EnemyTime;` from inside the gameplay. If the scope works, you should add var to here: `var EnemyTime = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 400);`

Comment: @mplungjan, My assumption was correct and I will try to improve on comment

Comment: I never said it was not. My suggestion to remove the line  was correct too :)

Comment: Good call on removing that. I added var in front of that line as per suggestion. However, the if conditional still isn't working properly. I receive the alert if reactionTime is less than EnemyTime, but when I close the alert bubble, I go straight to the EndScreen :(

Comment: If you see `alert("Wow you beat him! Congrats!");` then the code you have shown will never reach `EndScreen.style.visibility = "visible";` until NEXT time around - perhaps that is what happens? If you could click `<>` and create a [mcve] we would not have to guess what your code does

Comment: @mplungjan I apologize, this is my first time posting. There was an issue with my later code that I had to correct. I will definitely follow the formatting rules better next time....I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use floating point for your enemy time maths, i.e. 400.0 , else you are getting 0/1 seconds and not using milliseconds, and it is useing Math integer. Specifically cast your enemyTime as a float number, for the moment, if you print it it's probably an integer. its a MAJOR js coding detail that you will cost you hours of bughunting in the future if you think that 101/50 = 2.05, it isn't it equals 2, so divide by 50.0 and same with all second/ms tasks.

Use EnemyTime as a global variable for all scripts, at the moment, the code things you have a different function called EnemyTime in all scripts, the latter one has no value.

Use print to see when your else conditions work, specify a print in both an print the enemyTime value.

That's how you are supposed to resolve the issue, by printing the variables that are confusing.